# how to store cookie by using react in frontend adn django backend

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, django-rest-framework, axios

this code for  backend and I want after call URL store cookie but it still give me not sotre

```
class StoreCookie(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if 'cookie' in request.COOKIES:
            value = request.COOKIES['cookie']
            print('store')
            response = Response()
            return response
        else:
            response = Response()
            print('not store')
            response.set_cookie('cookie', 'MY COOKIE VALUE', httponly=False)
            return Response({"error": 'This Item Not Available For Now'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this code for frontend
`` axios.get(`url`,{withCredentials: true}) ``

Answer (score 0):

I'll work for the 2nd time. Because the first time it set the cookies (so it prints 'not store' and set the cookie).

When you run it for the 2nd time, then the cookie is there, so it will print read the cookie correctly

Comment: it keep print not store in the 2nd time

Comment: I don't know. Django, Just red the logic. Please do the following and debug the issue
Please check the browser dev tools if the cookies are stored or not after the call. if not stored, there is some issue in the django code (else section).